# Understanding image steganography by LSB substitution method

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, steganography

I am having a very hard time in understanding the [LSB based steganography](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df89/bacee8720f3b3be19d96e6eac6429a2a8130.pdf) method given in Section 2. The examples in the internet are very confusing and unclear. I am following the Matlab implementation https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41326-steganography-using-lsb-substitution and the paper titled, "A SURVEY ON IMAGE STEGANOGRAPHY USING LSB SUBSTITUTION 
TECHNIQUE " download link (https://irjet.net/archives/V4/i5/IRJET-V4I566.pdf)

Section 5 of this paper gives an example of the LSB based method. Suppose, `P1 = [10011011], P2 = [01101010], P3 = [11001100]` are the 3 bytes of the cover image into which the message `M =  [011]` is to be embedded. The result of the embedding is `P1 =  [10011010], P2 = [01101011], 
P3 =  [11001101]`.

I am clueless how this answer comes. Can somebody please help in giving the steps/working example to clear the concept?

Based on my understanding of the Matlab code, 
`Stego = uint8(round(bitor(bitand(x, bitcmp(2^n - 1, 8)) , bitshift(y, n - 8))));`

if `n` is the number of bits to be substituted, then the group of `n` bits are replaced by doing a complement/ comparison of the group of `n` bits of the cover image (`x` variable) with the `n` bits of the message (`y` variable). If the bits are same, then no replacement, else the bits are swapped. I dont't know if my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: It's quite straightforward really. You start with 3 bytes of data in your original image: P=[1001101**1**, 0110101**0**, 1100110**0**]. The least significant bits of these bytes are **1**, **0** and **0**. In LSB steganography, these least significant bits are replaced with the information you want to hide, which is **011** in this case. So the original 3 bytes are changed to [1001101**0**, 0110101**1**, 1100110**1**]. That's all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. According to the Matlab code, would the command `2^n` replace `k = 2^n` LSB bits? If `n = 4` then there would be `2^4` combinations and would the 4th LSB be replaced? Is this the actual algorithm. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fact that all 3 sources you're looking at talk about something different.

### Paper 2, section 5

This describes the most basic form of LSB pixel substitution steganography. Each pixel is described by 8 bits. For each pixel we clear out the LSB and substitute it with one bit of the secret message. For example,

```
pixels = [xxxxxxxa, xxxxxxxb]
message = [c, d]
stego_pixels = [xxxxxxxc, xxxxxxxd]
```

Where `x`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are bits and we don't care what `x` is.

### Paper 1, section 2

This is the generalised form of LSB pixel substitution steganography. Instead of embedding the secret in the LSB, you embed it in the k-most LSBs. If `k = 1`, then we have the simple form described above. The mathematical equations is this section mean the following:

1. We have an image of size MxN, with each pixel having a value between 0 and 255 (8 bits).
2. We have an n-bit message, with each bit being either 0 or 1. For example, for 12 bits it'd be `m = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l]`.
3. Since we'll be embedding k bits per pixel, we group our message bits in groups of k. Assume that `k = 3`, then, `m' = [abc, def, ghi, jkl]`. Obviously, each group can have a value between 0 and 2^k - 1. Furthermore, the number of groups in `m'` cannot exceed the size of our image, or we won't be able to embed the whole message.
4. We clear out the last k bits from each pixel and we substitute them with one group of `m'`. When you take the modulo of a number with 2^k, the remainder you get is the last k bits of the original number. So by subtracting them, we clear out the last k bits.
5. Similar to the previous step, if we want to extract the message, we take the modulo of each pixel with 2^k to get the last k bits, where we have embedded our message. It's trivial to stitch these bit groups and obtain the original message, `m`, back.

### Matlab code

This code hides an image of size MxN to a cover image of the same size. The idea here is the MSB holds the most information about the image and the LSB the least. For example, this is the bit plane decomposition of [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_plane#/media/File:Lichtenstein_bitplanes.png).

[image: Bit plane decomposition]

If we decide to hide k bits from the secret image, we want those to be the k most significant bits. Similarly, we can hide them in the k least significant bits of the cover image. The larger the k value, the more bits you'll hide from the secret for a more faithful reconstruction, but the more distortion you'll introduce to the cover.

Let's break down the nested functions in the code to see what they do. I'll use `k` instead of `n` to maintain consistency with the above sections.

`bitcmp(2^k - 1, 8)` creates the complement of 2^k - 1 for 8 bits. For example, if k = 3, then 2^k - 1 is like having the bits `00000111` and obviously its complement is `11111000`. We're going to use this number as a mask, so `mask = bitcmp(2^k - 1, 8)`.

`bitand(x, mask)` zeroes out the last k bits of the cover image, `x`. This is the [bitwise AND operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) and the reason we called the second part a mask is because anywhere we have a 1, we keep the original bit and anywhere we have a 0, we get a 0. Let's call `cleared_pixels = bitand(x, mask)`.

`bitshift(y, 8 - k)` keeps only the k most significant bits of the secret. For example, for k = 3 we achieve `abcxxxxx -> 00000abc`. This is done by shifting the number 5 places to the right. This is a [logical shift operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift#Example). We'll call this result `secret = bitshift(y, 8 - k)`.

Finally, `bitor(cleared_pixels, secret)` simply combines the two together. The cleared pixels have the last k bits cleared and the secret is at most k bits, so the two parts don't interact; we get a pure combination.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on the explanation about the Matlab code, it seems that the idea is more inclined towards the  first technique - described under Paper 2, Section 5. Is that so?

Comment: @RiaGeorge I would say it's more akin to paper 1, because `bitshift(y, 8 - k)` is pretty much `m'`, where you prepare the secret in groups of k bits and then embed them.

Comment: @RiaGeorge It's a bit of a special case in the way that no matter what k you choose, the secret will always be the size of the cover image. This is a result or writing a simple one-liner which takes advantage of Matlab's vectorisation when operations are applied to same-size matrices. And the secret you end up embedding, while it is losslessly extracted, it is only a lossy representation of the original secret.

Comment: @RiaGeorge The algorithm used in the code is very inefficient, considering how lossy it is. Loading the image in a pixel array is like trying to embed a bmp file, which is huge. Even if k = 1, the end result is a very loose approximation of the secret. But, if you load the raw binary data of a png, or jpg file, you should be able to embed the whole file with just k = 1, or pretty much what paper 2 describes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Matlab code gives very poor result in the extraction of the hidden image when `k=1`. The extracted hidden image is lossy with the MSE between the original image and the extracted being very high. It would be really awesome if you can provide a better improved way to work with the code. If needed I can post a new question. (Sorry, I am unable to upvote the answer through my mobile phone right now)

Comment: @RiaGeorge Like I said, read the file as is with and convert it to bits with `de2bi(fread(fopen(filename)), 8)`. Embed these bits to your cover image with the minimum k factor required, probably 1 or 2. When you extract your secret, you'll be able to reconstruct the original file.

Comment: Thank you once again. This is what I did: `x = de2bi(fread(fopen('cover.png')), 8);` but in the display, I reconverted `x` to `xx=bi2de(x)` and then `imshow(xx)`. However, I am getting a thin vertical line in the display. I am applying the code for rgb and then for grayscale images. FOr rgb imags, I am using the red channel only. After performing all operations on binary image, how do I convert properly to image (rgb and gray)? Thank you very much for continuous help.

Comment: When working with rgb images, I used ` cover_rgb =repmat(double(x),[1,1,3]); imshow(cover_rgb);` but this is giving wrong output.

Comment: @RiaGeorge `x` is the literal bytestream of the file. You want to write that to a file and then load it with `imread()`. If you have further problems you are encouraged to ask a new question. Ideally, comments here should be used for further clarification of the question/answers provided, not to troubleshoot other things.

Comment: I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679958/read-rgb-image-into-binary-and-display-it-as-rgb-in-matlab  Could you be kind enough to take a look and maybe if possible answer it? Thank you for your time and effort.