# Read RGB image into binary and display it as RGB in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, fread, steganography

This question is based on the one asked earlier [Understanding image steganography by LSB substitution method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638628/understanding-image-steganography-by-lsb-substitution-method/49649396?noredirect=1#comment86369785_49649396)

In order to make the code efficient and reduce the mean square error (MSE) the suggestion was: "read the file as is with and convert it to bits with `de2bi(fread(fopen(filename)), 8)`. Embed these bits to your cover image with the minimum k factor required, probably 1 or 2. When you extract your secret, you'll be able to reconstruct the original file." This is what I have been trying but somewhere I am doing wrong as I am not getting any display. However, the MSE has indeed reduced.  Basically, I am confused as to how to convert the image to binary, perform the algorithm on that data and display the image after extraction.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: You ask how to do this with using either RGB or grayscale images. To clarify, are you referring to the cover image here?

Comment: The dino image is 594138 bytes long, or times 8 as many bits. Your cover image has 512 * 512 * 3 pixels. You have 6.05 as many secrets bts as pixels in your cover, which means you have to embed in the 7 most significant bits in order to fit the whole message. In other words, this is too big a file. If you resized the secret to, say, 256x256, its file size would be much much smaller and it'd be more manageable.

Comment: @Reti43: Both the images are of same size and RGB. Embedding the RGB secret image (dino file) into RGB cover image in 7 most significant or 8 most significant bit planes of any one channel is okay for me. I can build upon that later once I understand what your suggestion was and how to implement it. I think I converted the image to binary the way you suggested and it does give lower MSE. But then the next problem is converting those binary to images in order to display. This I cannot understand how to do. Can you please help once again as you better understand the situation. thanks

Comment: @Reti43: As per your suggestion, I read the image using `imread` and then converted to binary `de2bi`. The LSB is applied on this binary image. But as you can see from the updated question, I cannot display the extracted image. The MSE has reduced but I cannot display the extracted image.

Comment: Removing the code in your question is counterproductive, because it's crucial to understanding your question and it's accessible by the revision history regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the byte stream instead of the pixel array of the secret will result to a smaller payload. How smaller it'll be depends on the image format and how repetitive the colours are.

`imread()` requires a filename and loads a pixel array if said filename is a valid image file. Loading the byte stream of the file and passing that to `imread()` makes no sense. What you want is this

```
% read in the byte stream of a file
fileID = fopen(filename);
secretBytes = fread(fileID);
fclose(fileID);

% write it back to a file
fileID = fopen(filename);
fwrite(fileID, secretBytes);
fclose(fileID);
```

Note that the cover image is loaded as a pixel array, because you'll need to modify it.

The size of your payload is `length(secretBytes) * 8` and this must fit in your cover image. If you decide to embed `k` bits per pixel, for all your colour planes, the following requirement must be met

```
secretBytes * 8 <= prod(size(coverImage)) * k
```

If you want to embed in only one colour plane, regardless of whether your cover medium is an RGB or greyscale, you need to modify that to

```
secretBytes * 8 <= size(coverImage,1) * size(coverImage,2) * k
```

If this requirement isn't met, you can choose to

- stop the process
- ask the user for a smaller file to embed
- increase k
- include more colour planes, if available

The following is a prototype for embedding in one colour plane in the least significant bit only (k = 1).

```
HEADER_LEN = 24;

coverImage = imread('lena.png');
secretBytes = uint8('Hello world'); % this could be any byte stream

%% EMBEDDING
coverPlane = coverImage(:,:,1);     % this assumes an RGB image
bits = de2bi(secretBytes,8)';
bits = [de2bi(numel(bits), HEADER_LEN) bits(:)'];
nBits = length(bits);
coverPlane(1:nBits) = bitset(coverPlane(1:nBits),1,bits);
coverImage(:,:,1) = coverPlane;

%% EXTRACTION
nBits = bi2de(bitget(coverPlane(1:HEADER_LEN),1));
extBits = bitget(coverPlane(HEADER_LEN+1:HEADER_LEN+nBits),1);
extractedBytes = bi2de(reshape(extBits',8,length(extBits)/8)')';
```

Along with your message bytes you have to embed the length of the secret, so the extractor knows how many bits to extract.

If you embed with k > 1 or in more than one colour planes, the logic becomes more complicated and you have to be careful how you implement the changes.

For example, you can choose to embed in each colour plane at a time until you run out of bits to hide, or you can flatten the whole pixel array with `coverImage(:)`, which will embed in the RGB of each pixel, one pixel at a time until you run out of bits.

If you embed with k > 1, you have to pad your `bits` vector with 0s until its length is divisible by `k`. Then you can combine your bits in groups of k with

```
bits = bi2de(reshape(a',k,length(bits)/k)')';
```

And to embed them, you want to resort back to using `bitand()` and `bitor()`.

```
coverPlane(1:nBits) = bitor(bitand(coverPlane(1:nBits), bitcmp(2^k-1,'uint8')), bits);
```

There are more details, like extracting exactly 24 bits for the message length and I can't stress enough you have to think very carefully how you implement all of those things. You can't just stitch parts from different code snippets and expect everything to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again. I have tried my best to put together the answer but I keep getting an error. I have put up the code in the updated portion of the Question. Then how do I display the extracted file? Should I convert it to `uint8`?Could you kindly take a look?

Answer (score 2):

I've made some modifications to your code to get this to work regardless of what the actual image is.  However, they both need to be either colour or grayscale.  There are also some errors your code that would not allow me to run it on my version of MATLAB.

Firstly, you aren't reading in the images properly.  You're opening up a byte stream for the images, then using `imread` on the byte stream to read in the image.  That's wrong - just provide a path to the actual file.

Secondly, the images are already in `uint8`, so you can perform the permuting and shifting of bits natively on this.

The rest of your code is the same as before, except for the image resizing.  You don't need to specify the number of channels.  Also, there was a syntax error with `bitcmp`.  I used `'uint8'` instead of the value `8` as my version of MATLAB requires that you specify a string of the expected data type.  The value `8` here I'm assuming you mean 8 bits, so it makes sense to put `'uint8'` here.

I'll also read your images directly from Stack Overflow.  I'll assume the dinosaur image is the cover while the flower is the message:

```
%%% Change
x = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iod2d.png');         % cover message
y  = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg5mr.png');    % message image
n = input('Enter the no of LSB bits to be subsituted- ');

                                     %%% Change
S = uint8(bitor(bitand(x,bitcmp(2^n-1,'uint8')),bitshift(y,n-8))); %Stego
E = uint8(bitand(255,bitshift(S,8-n))); %Extracted

origImg = double(y);   %message image
distImg = double(E);   %extracted image

[M N d] = size(origImg);
distImg1=imresize(distImg,[M N]); % Change

figure(1),imshow(x);title('1.Cover image')
figure(2),imshow(y);title('2.Message to be hide')
figure(3),imshow((abs(S)),[]);title('3.Stegnographic image')
figure(4),imshow(real(E),[]); title('4.Extracted image');
```

This runs for me and I manage to reconstruct the message image.  Choosing the number of bits to be about 4 gives you a good compromise between the cover and message image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there are a couple of concerns. (1) According to the answer to the previous question of mine, I should improve the code to get better extraction of the image. For that it was suggested to convert the image to binary and the operations be done on the binary image. This reduced the mean square error. However, I could not display the image since probably I was not using proper operations to read and display an image from decimal to binary. That is why I posted this question since after converting the image to binary, I could not display using `imshow()`.

Comment: The suggestion was: "read the file as is with and convert it to bits with de2bi(fread(fopen(filename)), 8). Embed these bits to your cover image with the minimum k factor required, probably 1 or 2. When you extract your secret, you'll be able to reconstruct the original file." This is what I have been trying but cannot do so. Could you please provide the code on how to apply the algorithm on the binary version of the image? The present version of the code gives a very high mean square error for bit planes 1-4. (2) Moreover, the extracted image is of poor brightness in the present version.

Comment: Use `im2bw` on top of the image.  That converts the image to binary.

Comment: Sorry, I could not follow which line you refer to. If the original images-cover and the secret and converted to binary, how would I display the extracted image?

Comment: @RiaGeorge I don't know enough of your domain. Sorry. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Ria's confusion is this: the code in your answer is the algorithm that the he had stumbled upon previously. I explained to him how it works and commented that embedding only a few bitplanes of the images is lossy. If the secret is in a compressed format, then it should be smaller than a bmp, i.e., loading it as an image array. So what he could do is read in the 1s and 0s of the png file and embed those, so he could reconstruct the original secret. Obviously he needed to write that code from scratch instead of applying bits and pieces of that logic to the other algorithm.

Comment: @Reti43 ok that makes sense. It explains the nonsense about loading in the byte stream first and feeding it into `imread`. To me it's apparent that the original question is taking pieces from other algorithms and trying to make the current question work.

Comment: @rayryeng: I have applied the algorithm to binary data as per suggestions. As per the suggestion, I should convert the image to binary. So, first I did `imread()` then `de2bi`. The method on binary image gives improved MSE. However, I cannot display the image. Would it be possible for you to revise your answer on how to display the image after it is converted to binary? Could you please see the updated Question.